# What methods on choosing the objects to be modelled?

Tags: object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design

From my conversation with @Steve in the question [Is there any philosophical theory behind the concept of object in computer science?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/99710/19487) on Philosophy Stack Exchange:

---

**Steve**: More often than not, programmers haven't in fact been equipped to understand how things work in the real world - not even their own computers, let alone other people's jobs.

When programmers try to model the "real world" with objects, they more often come up with models that are simpleton in that they omit crucial details or workings that actually characterise the real world, but also models that are overly complicated in that they encourage focus on irrelevant aspects of the real world instead of modelling the clerical work in the simplest way possible.

So for example, new OO programmers often end up trying to think about modelling objects representing patients and their behaviours at the hospital, rather than thinking about how to model clerical records representing data about patients (and which needs to be primarily tailored around thr clinician's idea of what is relevant to record, and the clerk's view about how to work effectively with the records, nothing to do with what is "real" or not about the patient).

**Ooker**: Isn't that the record should be on one person? I get that a patient can have different records, but then each record can be a sub-object of the person object? I think the reason new programmers fail to tailor to what the clinician and the clerk need are simply because they don't study medical science and health administration?

**Steve**: A *patient* doesn't have records. A *hospital* has records. You're right that an absence of training is a problem, but so is mis-training. The big idea was once that you model "the real world" with objects, and that you think about what "attributes" and "behaviours" those objects have. But records don't have behaviours - clerks possess all the "behaviours" of a manual record-keeping system - and records may be about a patient but are not thereby an attribute of the patient. The reality is that what methods represent are not "behaviours" of records (and certainly not behaviours of patients), but *defined operations upon* the records. And often, those operations do not belong to one record or another, but transform many records at once without being focussed on any single one of them.

**Ooker**: This is cool. I understand it now. However I still wonder what keep us from not having patient objects? Because you can arbitrary create whatever objects to make your thinking clear? Say we have a record operation to do covid test. While strictly speaking that we do those operations via the records, yes, but in our minds and actions we still assign them to the patient by saying "test the patient", not "update the record that the patient is tested". I think this is where we need to use philosophy of mind and language. I'm general, do you know any resource on how to pick the correct objects?

**Steve**: If the programmer "arbitrarily creates", then that is some way away from the "modelling real-world objects" approach I referred to, isn't it? When you say "we test the patient", that "we" is almost certainly not the programmer, and it may not even be the computer user, and the test may not even be contemporaneous with the entry of data into the computer.

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any useful resources in a neat package - I'm speaking from unsystematic research of materials drawn from many decades (including before I was born), anecdotes from other professionals, personal experience of both business and programming, and my own thought. The design of record-keeping systems is a craft activity subject to a great deal of variation, with very few settled questions or consistent approaches, and no effective systems for reproduction of knowledge amongst professionals or across generations.

---

I wonder if there is any resource on how to decide which objects are best used to model the real system? Or is it very system-specific and it's not possible to have a general answer?

Comment: You might be interested in "domain-driven design", which involves delineating a bounded context (which aspect of the problem domain does this component address?), identifying the entities in this context, and giving them clear names that facilitate communication with subject matter experts. There's also the older technique of identifying objects, attributes, and methods in natural-language description: doctor *is a* user. Doctor *can view* patient records. Patient *has a* name.

Comment: Modeling stuff is actually an activity that isn't unique to software development - it's used, in one way or another, in engineering, statistics, applied math, all of science, and likely in other disciplines. The models may look very different and the approaches to modeling are varied, but the overall principles are shared - you're looking to create some abstract representation of something that is of interest to your discipline/project (i.e. a representation that's simplified/distilled to essentials, compared to the real thing). It just captures how you think about the thing of interest.

Comment: The key thing, however, is whether or not your model (your conceptualization) actually works for what it is intended (in software: does it allow you to achieve the properties you're after - correctness, maintainability, scalability, performance, clarity; in science: does it actually make the correct predictions).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović, I don't think the issue is about whether other disciplines model, but about how modelling should be done in software and what approaches contribute to success in that task. In software, what the model is intended for is often ill-defined - programmers are often effectively tasked with clarifying what a computer ought to do. Once clarified, the intentions are usually multi-faceted in a bespoke way which isn't simple to analyse and for which an existing analysis doesn't exist.

Comment: @Steve - I was not answering the question in the title, but more commenting on the underlying conceptual question, which is why I posted this as a comment. I'm just saying that the core principles are the same and transcend programming. Of course the model is ill-defined - it's the job of the modeler (the developer (team), the scientist) to define it by studying the domain. Of course it novel and challenging to analyze - that's why you're doing the modeling. Even when you're not explicitly doing the modeling, you *are* doing the modelling - just haphazardly.

Comment: Meta discussion: [Why is the question asking about guideline on modelling a domain unfocused?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9558/192731)

Comment: If you find your vocabulary constantly referring to an item, in the domain of object oriented programming (just one approach out of many), the decision is to create an object for that item.  So, in a sense, it depends on how you describe your problem and its components.

Comment: It might be worth considering [Conway's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law). It focuses on an organizations communication structure. But objects are typically simply the nodes in that structure. A UML class diagram shows that structure by showing what knows about what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if there is any resource on how to decide which objects are best used to model the real system? Or is it very system-specific and it's not possible to have a general answer?

It is very system-specific.

There is a complexity in programming that is widely under-appreciated.

To demonstrate, you wouldn't ask a mechanical engineer "are there resources that can help you to decide what components a space rocket would have?".

The obvious reply is that only a space programme is capable of providing those answers. And those answers won't apply to submarines.

Comment: surely that a random mechanical engineer cannot get deep on the topic, but they can still propose some **first intuitions** based on **established laws** (e.g. "well, at least you need to win the Earth's gravity. Perhaps using a combustion engine and place it downward?", "well, at least you need to get yourself heavier than the water itself. Perhaps having a tank and let water in and out?") Imagine a book for kids that briefly explains how common machines of various fields are made of. That would be a good guideline I think

Comment: @Ooker, but would it be helpful for the senior programmer to stand there, sucking air like a car mechanic, and declare "well, I think you need to process data; maybe using some kind of computer with a user interface"? The kind of guidance about design that programmers would find useful, must be far more detailed than that. The space of potential solutions is so large that programming work is often about searching and examining possibilities.

Comment: Still, if the project is not private, they can still share how they model their specific projects. Maybe modeling a car company is different to modeling another a car company, but that's OK. I only need an example. Is there any connection where various engineers contribute to it?

Comment: @Ooker, ah well even if we set aside the question of corporate intellectual property, the reality is that even though a codebase embodies the end result of designing a record-keeping system, the code doesn't necessarily explain why design decisions were made, or in what circumstances they were made and how the design choices were suitable to those circumstances. Sometimes suitability might be only accidental. Companies who develop in-house software often don't even have these things documented at all, let alone documented in a coherent way suitable for a teaching purpose. (1/2)

Comment: And of course there's usually little for a particular business to gain from the documentation, relative to the expense of its production (and constant maintenance, if they want it to embody current business reality and not historical knowledge). It only reflects one model, which doesn't generalise, so it doesn't have much value on the market. A learner would need many examples, and time to absorb and scrutinise them all. (2/2)

Comment: how about non-profit organizations and academic researches? Don't they have enough incentives for making one?

Comment: @Ooker, the only advantage is to help train and upskill the entire profession, but that benefit is so economically general that only a state-owned firm, or old-style private cartels and national champions, are capable of charging the entire economy for the relevant work to be done. A lot of the computer technology development in the 60s fell out of the American space programme, and obviously the workers it helped train were around for decades after.

Comment: what do you think about [domain-driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design "Domain-driven design - Wikipedia")? Is it the answer to the question?

Comment: @Ooker, I'm not fully abreast of its details, but my understanding of its main tenet is basically "let the record-keeping be designed by the experts in that domain" (domain being a fancy word for the business context, in a highly non-specific way). That doesn't answer your question, because it doesn't explain how *those* experts arrive at their design - it just assumes those roles exist, and that nothing need be said about how those roles work. Also, like other supposed schemes and methods, practitioners don't necessarily speak with one voice about what DDD is or how it works.

Answer (score 2):

> Or is it very system-specific and it's not possible to have a general answer?

This. Your objects match the *business* problem you're trying to solve. For example, while Formula 1 and a taxi business both involve cars and driving, the objects you want in one are very, very different from the objects you want in the other.